# Localization issue on CakePHP application

Tags: cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-2.4

I am developing a CakePHP 2 application.

My problem is that I dont know how execute an instruction after user clicks over a link.

My intention is writting a value in the Session. The user clicks over a flag icon, so he specifies the language for his session.

Then I would run

```
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'eng');
```

How can I solve this issue?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you've clicked on `eng` language link i.e. http://mycakeapp.com/?lang=eng

Now you can set the English language by using `beforefilter` callback in your appcontroller
as like this.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!empty($this->request->query['lang'])) {
        $this->Session->write('Config.language', $this->request->query['lang']);
    }

    if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
        Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));// setting language here...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have what you say in my beforeFilter action but nothing. At fact, my plugin is not showing my bootstrap.php default language. What I could do?

Comment: what error you're getting ? try to echo the session value in `beforeFilter`, Make sure you're using session component, may be you're overwriting the `$components` array of your controller

Comment: the session variable is working right. I have my Configure.language as 'eng', so it should take the correct .po, which is in Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po within my Plugin path. Isn't it?

Comment: yes. it'll take, FYI for English you don't need to specify any translations. what problem you're getting here ..., and also it is `Configure::write('Config.language')` and not `Configure.language` as you said

Comment: I have achieved to work right in the App part, so I will you your solution as valid. I dont know why is not working in my plugin, but I will carry on trying. Thanks!

Comment: Can you put the code of your plugin, so I'll do my best to resolve this problem

Comment: I have solved the problem! It was a spelling issue. I change mi default.po for PluginName.po but it doesnt working again. Then I changed it for plugin_name.po and it worked! I edit my post with the solution for rest users?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should create an controller action that accept the lang attribute like.

```
<?php

    // in settings controller
    funciton select_lang($lang = 'eng'){
      $this->autoRender = false;
      $this->Session->write('Config.language', $lang);
      return $this->redirect($this->refrer());
    }
?>
```

and in the view you can simply pass the value for the var lang.

Comment: It sounds like but it isnt working... I forgot to say its a plugin. I put your code in <Plugin>AppController so when I click over flag it redirect to my new action, but the language displayed is the same